# Context manager scope

Tags: python

I understand context manager does not create a scope in Python. However, why does this code:

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wt', dir=F"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))}/assets/fetch/", delete=False, suffix=".xml") as fp:
    fp.write(generate_xml(param))
    from time import sleep
    sleep(.05)

    MODEL_PATH = fp.name
    model = mujoco_py.load_model_from_path(MODEL_PATH)
```

Give an error of "file not found", but moving the model outside the context manager does not.

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='wt', dir=F"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))}/assets/fetch/", delete=False, suffix=".xml") as fp:
        fp.write(generate_xml(param))
        from time import sleep
        sleep(.05)

        MODEL_PATH = fp.name
    model = mujoco_py.load_model_from_path(MODEL_PATH)
```

MODEL_PATH is not defined anywhere else in the function.

Comment: Please double check the indentation of that second snippet…

Comment: Since the error you're getting must be decided inside `mujoco_py`, and we do not have the content of this function, I don't think we can answer your question.

Comment: @deceze It is correct? The last line is just de-indented one time compared to the first

Comment: @IMCoins mujoco_py is here: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py but I think this is a scoping issue or a tempfile issue